# What do I return from a POST action called from an external site?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a `Payment` controller, which exposes an `HttpPost` action method called `Notify`.  This action is posted to when my external payment service sends me an *Immediate Payment Notification* (IPN), and it's sole purpose is to update my data based on the data I receive in the IPN.  It never returns a view, so what should my action method return?  I'm sure the payment service wants an HTTP 200 or something in response to the IPN post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could return an [empty result](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.emptyresult.aspx):

```
return new EmptyResult();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
return new HttpStatusCodeBoundedResult(200, "IPN accepted");
return new HttpStatusCodeBoundedResult(400, "Bad IPN request");
```

.

```
public class HttpStatusCodeBoundedResult : HttpStatusCodeResult
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of <see cref="HttpStatusCodeBoundedResult"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="statusCode">The status code.</param>
    public HttpStatusCodeBoundedResult(int statusCode) : base(statusCode)
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of <see cref="HttpStatusCodeBoundedResult"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="statusCode">The status code.</param>
    /// <param name="statusDescription">The status description. Will be 
    ///   truncated to  512 characters and have \r\n characters stripped.</param>
    public HttpStatusCodeBoundedResult(int statusCode, string statusDescription)
        : base(statusCode, ApplyHttpResponseBoundary(statusDescription, 512))
    {
    }

    private static string ApplyHttpResponseBoundary(string input, int length)
    {
        input = input.Replace("\r", string.Empty).Replace("\n", string.Empty);

        return input.Length <= length ? input : input.Substring(0, length);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, nice to know there is a HttpStatusCodeResult, and good thoughts on deriving from it.

Comment: I absolutely don't recommend using the raw HttpStatusCodeResult, after having production systems crashing for getting a message that exceeded 512 chars in the description or had a line break in it. I was like -_-. I can't understand why MS would rather have your website crash here than fix it themselves.

Answer (score 0):

You can just make it return `void`.